# Installing JDK on Linux

Tags: java, centos

I’m trying to install JDK on Centos, but I’m getting an error:

```
[root@www opt]# rpm -ivh /opt/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jdk                    ########################################### [100%]
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/db/lib/derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar;533ab42a: cpio: read
```

Where can be problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the md5sum of the downloaded file against these values here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html ?

If the md5sum does not check, it must be a broken download.

Answer (score 1):

**A short answer:** try downloading and installing again.

**A longer answer:**
Even though you are getting this, the jdk is getting installed. Sort of. This seems to be an error in the packaging but it is not fatal.  Here is the output from my machine.  In the example I cat'd the release file so you can see what CentOS I'm using and did an md5sum on the rpm I'm using.  You'll notice that it doesn't match the md5sum from the [Oracle site link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-binaries-checksum-1956892.html) (provided above by Kristof).

Next, I did an ls on the target directory for the jdk /usr/java/ so you can see that it is empty.  Then ran the rpm install and did another ls to show that some files are there.

[image: output from test]

Of course, this defeats the purpose of using rpm, because the install information is not going to go into the rpm database.  If I query the database it doesn't come up and it's missing the links that usually get installed pointing to 'latest' and 'default'

[image: not in rpm db]

So I took a guess that maybe there is a mirror that might have a bad rpm and went to the Oracle site and downloaded the file again.  I gave it a different name so that I can compare the two files.  This time it was successful.

In the screen shot below you can see the two files.  The newest download being the one I called jdk-7u51-linux-x86_64.rpm.  You can see the md5sum shows the files are different, but on the new file, the md5 matches the Oracle site.  I removed the directory that was created by the failed install and then ran the rpm -ivh command and it completed successfully.  The ls on the /usr/java directory shows all the correct stuff and querying the rpm database shows it was installed.  Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple script which you can find [here](https://github.com/Karmadon/vagrant-apache-cluster/blob/master/scripts/init.sh)

It's for Centos rpm, but you can edit script and change rpm to tar.gz for example
Also you can change version or env in variables bellow

```
BASE_URL="technetwork/java/javase/downloads"
BASE_URL_OUTPUT="$(curl -s  -L0 http://www.oracle.com/${BASE_URL}/)"
JAVA_ENVIRONMENT="JDK"
JAVA_BASE_VERSION=8
DOWNLOAD_SITE="$(echo $BASE_URL_OUTPUT | grep -m 1 -io "${JAVA_ENVIRONMENT}${JAVA_BASE_VERSION}-downloads-[0-9]*.html" -- | tail -1)"
echo "DOWNLOAD_SITE="$DOWNLOAD_SITE
DOWNLOAD_LINK_OUTPUT="$(curl -s -L -j -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://www.oracle.com/${BASE_URL}/${DOWNLOAD_SITE} |  grep -io "filepath.*${JAVA_ENVIRONMENT}-[${JAVA_BASE_VERSION}].*linux[-_]x64[._].*\(rpm\)" -- | cut -d '"' -f 3 | tail -1)"
echo "DOWNLOAD_LINK_OUTPUT="$DOWNLOAD_LINK_OUTPUT
curl -L -o java_rpm_packet.rpm -b "oraclelicense=a" $DOWNLOAD_LINK_OUTPUT
```

and install with

```
yum localinstall -y java_rpm_packet.rpm
```